# not evalute variables before runtime in for loop

Tags: bash, random, evaluation

Is there any hack to not evaluate variables in bash before runtime? I have a kind of for loop like this:
the problem is i have it inside a echo... otherwise this works great!

```
for i in $(seq 0 100); do echo $(echo $RANDOM % 10 | bc); done
```

the result is for example always 3...

Comment: The pipe to `bc` is hardly necessary if all you want is always a single digit.  `r=$RANDOM; q=${r%?}; echo ${r#$q}` does this in pure `sh` syntax.

Comment: It works for me as written (i.e. I get different random numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside your problem: your solution uses 2 external processes, 1 pipe, 1 subprocess for a trivial exercise. Pure Bash:

```
for (( CNTR=0; CNTR<=100; CNTR+=1 )); do
  echo  $((RANDOM%10))
done
```

Comment: The required echo of an additional string is missing here: `echo  "foo $((RANDOM%10))"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
for i in $(seq 0 100);

do
    echo $RANDOM % 10 | bc
done
```

I see ... with echo this works for me:

```
for i in $(seq 0 100);

do
    echo "foo $(echo $RANDOM % 10 | bc)"
done
```

Comment: yes for me too, but i need to echo a string and then have the random value: echo "foo $(echo $RANDOM % 10 | bc)"

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, a brace expansion could be used:

```
for i in {0..100}; do
  echo $((RANDOM%10))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The traditional solution when you want to preempt variable interpolation is to use quoting and `eval`.  This is not as elegant as a pure-Bash solution, but obviously more portable.

```
 for i in $(seq 0 100); do
   eval 'echo $RANDOM % 10 | bc'
 done
```

This is just a minimal refactoring of your original code, and I post it only for completeness.

Answer (score -1):

You have a couple of problems here and I don't think either of them have to do with variable evaluation.

The first is that `$RANDOM` isn't defined here. Maybe you have it set to `3` somewhere and that's why you always get `3` as output?

The second is that you don't need both those `echo`s. Omit the outer one, along with the `$()` around the other one.

Comment: $RANDOM is an internal bash funtion. It is defined!

Comment: yes $RANDOM is defined by bash... i think the problem is that bash evaluate the value before processing the for BUT only in a echo! if i dont use echo twice, i get correct result...

Comment: Holy moly, I never knew that!